# Input JS file within insDLJS environment

Tags: pdf, javascript

The [eforms](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eforms) package provides the `insDLJS` environment to insert document-level JavaScript into a PDF file. It would be convenient (for code reuse and syntax highlighting, among other things) to put the JavaScript into its own file, and input it using, e.g.,

```
\begin{insDLJS}{macros}{}
\input{macros.js}
\end{insDLJS}
```

But this just inserts the string `\input{macros.js}` into the .djs file, and gives an error.

I could instead put the `\begin` and `\end` lines into `macros.js`, but that file is then no longer valid JavaScript (and so can't be reused in a web page, for example).

Is there a way of inserting the contents of a file within the `insDLJS` environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easily done with pdfTeX built-in commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

%just to create some example external JavaScript file
\begin{filecontents*}{macros.js}
  app.alert("hello world!");
\end{filecontents*}

% create PDF object from file content
\immediate\pdfobj stream file {macros.js} 

%create JavaScript action
\immediate\pdfobj{ <</S/JavaScript /JS \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R>> } 

%register JavaScript action for execution when the document is opened
\pdfnames{ /JavaScript << /Names [(someDocLevelJS) \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R ] >> }

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Multiple JS files can be included as well; there is no upper limit. The associated JavaScript Actions just have to be registered in the `/Names` array:

```
\documentclass{article}

%just to create some example external JavaScript files
\begin{filecontents*}{macrosA.js}
  app.alert("hello world!");
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{macrosB.js}
  app.alert("here comes the sun.");
\end{filecontents*}

% create PDF object from file content
\immediate\pdfobj stream file {macrosA.js}

%create JavaScript action
\immediate\pdfobj{ <</S/JavaScript /JS \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R>> }
\edef\actionA{\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}

% create PDF object from file content
\immediate\pdfobj stream file {macrosB.js}

%create JavaScript action
\immediate\pdfobj{ <</S/JavaScript /JS \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R>> }
\edef\actionB{\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}

%register JavaScript actions for execution when the document is opened
\pdfnames{ /JavaScript << /Names [ (someDocLevelJS) \actionA \space (otherDocLevelJS) \actionB ] >> }

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. I have a follow-up that's probably not worth posting as a separate question: Is there a simple way to import two JS files into the same PDF output?

Comment: @StephenPowell :  Multiple files are no problem.

Comment: Perfect. (I thought I'd tried all sensible combinations to import two JS files, but apparently not that one.)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55960/im-not-the-language-youre-looking-for) for inspiration, I have come up with a hack:

Add the lines

```
$=0;/*
\begin{insDLJS}{form}{}%*/
```

and

```
//\end{insDLJS}
```

at the start and end of the .js file, and import it using:

```
\catcode`\$=14
\input{Plan_mark_sheet.js}
\catcode`\$=3
```

The first `\catcode` command causes LaTeX to interpret `$` as starting a single-line comment, and hence to ignore the first line in the .js file. In JavaScript, the first line simply defines a new variable, which is never used (`$` is a valid variable name and `var` is optional).

This is obviously an unsatisfactory solution, and I welcome more sensible answers.

Comment: This is so ugly I am tempted to downvote my own answer.